# Select count of different flags in a column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table:

```
id  flag
1    Y
1    Y
1    Y
1    N
1    N
2    Y
2    N
2    N
3    Y
3    N
```

i want to do as select statement which will give me the following output.

```
id   count_flag_Y   count_flag_N
 1        3               2
 2        1               2
 3        1               1
```

I was trying using the `select case` method but getting syntax error.

```
SELECT id,SUM(CASE WHEN flag= 'Y') as count_flag_Y,
SUM(CASE WHEN flag= 'N') as count_flag_N
from tablename
GROUP BY id
```

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query was not far off, you only have a slight problem with the `CASE` expressions.  Try this:

```
SELECT id,
       SUM(CASE WHEN flag= 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_flag_Y,
       SUM(CASE WHEN flag= 'N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_flag_N
FROM tablename
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 3):

You are very close, but in MySQL the `CASE` is not needed:

```
SELECT id, SUM(flag = 'Y') as count_flag_Y,
       SUM(flag = 'N') as count_flag_N
FROM tablename
GROUP BY id;
```

MySQL treats boolean expressions like integers in a numeric context, with "1" for true and "0" for false.